# Is there someway to change the content of a page with the htaccess file?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

I just wanted to know if there is someway to use the htaccess file to chnage the content of a page(s). Maybe something sort of like the redirect, but instead of sending the user to another page, it would just change the content of the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, `mod_rewrite` will serve up another page in the place of the requested without changing the url. There are [many questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) covering the topic of `mod_rewrite` that you can browse.

#### Example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page1.html$ page2.html
```

This will serve the content of `page2.html` when `page1.html` is requested while leaving the addressbar reading `http://somesite.com/page1.html`.

Comment: But is there a way to physically change the content of the page? The problem is, I dont need just page1 to redirect to page0 and show page1, I am also going to need page2 to redirect to page0 and show page2, and page3 to redirect to page0, and show page3

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule * handler.php
```

Where handler.php conatins the logic to decide which page should be loaded based on the HTTP_REFER parameter. That is, unless you have some reason for not doing an approach like this

Answer (score 0):

Check out **mod_ext_filter** Apache Module
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html

**Using sed to replace text in the response**

```
# mod_ext_filter directive to define a filter which
# replaces text in the response
#
ExtFilterDefine fixtext mode=output intype=text/html \
cmd="/bin/sed s/verdana/arial/g"

<Location />
# core directive to cause the fixtext filter to
# be run on output
SetOutputFilter fixtext
</Location>
```